# Qcache doesn't store anything in Qt 5.6

Tags: c++, qt, memory, qtcore, qt5.6

I'm trying to store **QStrings** in the **QCache** but after I close the application and run it again, the cache is empty again.

here is my cpp code:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Select a ply file"), homeDir, ".ply (*.ply)");
fileCache.insert(12, &fileName);
qDebug() << QString("# items in cache: ") + QString::number(fileCache.count());
ui->file_name_textEdit->insertPlainText(fileName);
```

and I have the cache declared in the header:

```
QCache<int, QString> fileCache;
```

I have also tried storing a tmp value because before i was receiving this memory leak error:

```
free(): invalid size: 0x00007fffa0d96600 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7fed3ebc1725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ff4a)[0x7fed3ebc9f4a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fed3ebcdabc]
/home/pendar/projects/paintsquad/build/pcl_visualizer(_ZN6QCacheIi7QStringE5clearEv+0x39)[0x473b0f]
/home/pendar/projects/paintsquad/build/pcl_visualizer(_ZN6QCacheIi7QStringED1Ev+0x19)[0x46f3d1]
/home/pendar/projects/paintsquad/build/pcl_visualizer(_ZN9PCLViewerD1Ev+0x6a)[0x468532]
/home/pendar/projects/paintsquad/build/pcl_visualizer(main+0x83)[0x463c79]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fed3eb6a830]
/home/pendar/projects/paintsquad/build/pcl_visualizer(_start+0x29)[0x463b29]
```

So I tried this:

```
QString *tmp = new QString("hi");
fileCache.insert(12, tmp);
```

Now I'm not getting any errors, but the cache is still empty on restart!

Comment: `QCache` does not persist across closing the application.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting as well, but I couldn't find out if that's the case in the documentation. I think maybe [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) is a better class to use in this case.

Comment: Yes `QSettings` would be a choice for what you want..

Comment: `QCache` is a container just like a `QVector` is. You wouldn't imagine a `QVector` will persist, neither will `QCache`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I needed to use [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) instead, which provides persistancy across closing and opening the application.

Comment: or you can store your paths in a sqlite database, I think this is more suitable in your case. . .